# Three.js PointLight fails with over 2 lights

Tags: html, webgl, three.js

Take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PRz4G/

You can see four white points about a blue one. Each of those points is supposed to have a light in the same place, but three of them have failed to work.

Look at this array in the fiddle:

```
var lights = {
    0: [712699, 0, 0],
    1: [732699, 0, 0],
    2: [722699, 10000, 0],
    3: [722699, -10000, 0],
    //4:[722699, 0, 10000],
    //5:[722699, 0, -10000]
};
```

If you comment out 2 and 3 as well, you can see that two lights render successfully. Uncomment 2 and we're back down to one working light. Uncomment 3 and 4 and now we have a full shader initialisation error.

What did I do wrong?

**Update:** 
The problem was display driver specific and is now working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This answer refers to an older version of three.js, and is no longer relevant. The `maxLights` parameter has been removed.

---

First of all, you need to set the `maxLights` parameter:

```
renderer: new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { maxLights: 6 } );
```

It defaults to 4, otherwise. With this change, I see 6 lights.

Your demo, as written, works for me, also. (4 lamps cast light onto the sphere.)

You may be having a hardware issue, too, preventing more than 2 lights. It could be an inferior GPU.

The good news is your code works with this change. :-)

Comment: Hmm, I added that attribute and it didn't change - I'm still only seeing one light cast when more than two lights are present.

This has happened on two computers; one I have no idea about the graphics but this one has an ATI HD 6970  - so I don't think it's a hardware issue.

Comment: Yep. Adding the maxLights gets rid of the shader error, but it's still only plotting one lightpath on the canvas - this is what I'm seeing: http://i.imgur.com/YfkHv.png

Comment: And that's on Windows, right? Maybe ANGLE can't handle it for some reason. Works fine on all my systems, including on the chromebook which has Intel HD integrated graphics.

Comment: Yes - this is in Windows 7 64bit pro on both machines I've tried; Firefox and Chrome both behave the same.

Comment: Just looked at this on an iMac in the office, and it does indeed work correctly. Must be a Windows bug. A very, very annoying Windows bug!

Comment: Have a look this thread for info about ANGLE limitations: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2126. Also see this older one: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/346.

Comment: I admit, I don't quite understand all of that! I did notice that it is actually rendering the intensity of all of the lights I requested, it's just putting them all in the x,y,z coords of the first light. I changed Firefox to use webgl.prefer-native-gl but now it's causing three.js to error out.

Comment: Well, this appears to be machine-specific. Maybe @mrdoob has a final suggestion...

Comment: @WizPip Oh, that's interesting piece of info. Maybe you could report it as a bug on github? It's likely to be a ANGLE issue but only alteredq would know.

Comment: There's a few more ideas in this post: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2505

Comment: I've accepted this answer, although it wasn't really an answer! The current ATI drivers on Win7x64 for my GPU seem to have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue with Chrome, but you must edit the shortcut and add

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --use-gl=desktop
```

With this you can cast any light as you want.

Comment: The problem was specific to ATI drivers for certain graphics cards on Windows. My specific problem has now gone away.